# Will upgrading PHP break JOOMLA?

Tags: joomla

I have a client who has JOOMLA! V1.5.1, and it currently is running on PHP 4.4.9. Does anyone know if upgrading to PHP5 break my site? Will upgrading to a newer JOOMLA! version break my site?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have a staging or test environment to try it out first? _Break_ is such a general term.

Comment: No, the environment is very unfriendly. If I ask the host to upgrade the PHP then thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a few functions on Joomla 1.5.1 that won't work if you upgrade to PHP 5.3+. Therefore you should also upgrade Joomla to 1.5.26 to ensure maximum security and stability for that particular version. Once both PHP and Joomla have been upgraded, everything will work smoothly.

To upgrade your PHP version, you will need to talk to your host, and why he is still running his servers on PHP 4.49 I do not know.

To update Joomla to the latest version, I would recommend download this package:

[Joomla 1.5.0 to 1.5.26](http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16891/73384/Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.26-Stable-Patch_Package.zip)

I know its not the update for 1.5.1, but it will still work.

As for upgrading to Joomla 2.5, this doesnt have to be done. It is entirely up to you. Just be sure that all your etension will be compatible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing must change if you just upgrade PHP. Is there custom PHP build used or installed from packes (like .rpm or .deb)?
If you have simple wibsite and will follow guidelines on upgrading Joomla ( listed here: http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5 ) then process must go smoothly.
But if there are any extensions which do not have their Joomla 2.5 versions, you'll get in trouble because old ones wimply won't work after upgrade.
Use akeeba backup to backup your site before upgrade and try to backup/restore at separate place to just have a proctice. I confgure it to use zip format because it does not require any extra software to restore site, but that's up to you.